# How to fetch distinct records from SQL Server Compact database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

How do I get unique records from multiple tables using SQL Server Compact?

I tried with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT Tbl_Customer.Name, Tbl_Room.Room_Number
FROM Tbl_Customer 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Room ON Tbl_Customer.Customer_number = Tbl_Room.Customer_Number 
WHERE Tbl_Customer.Customer_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT Tbl_Customer.Customer_number 
                                       FROM Tbl_Customer)
```

Comment: Have you tried: SELECT DISTINCT Tbl_Customer.Name, Tbl_Room.Room_Number FROM

Comment: yes i tried but its returning all duplicates record

Comment: i would like to mention one thing, actually Customer_Number is of nvarchar data type.

Comment: i want to retrieve records based on one column value ie Customer_Number column which is of nvarchar type

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why there is this WHERE statement. You are trying to get records from Tbl_Customer that have Customer_number existing in the same table - Tbl_Customer. Without this condition, you can use

```
SELECT c.Name, r.Room_Number
FROM Tbl_Customer c
INNER JOIN Tbl_Room r ON c.Customer_number = r.Customer_Number 
GROUP BY c.Name, r.Room_Number
```

I hope it helps.

EDIT: In this case SELECT DISTINCT should give the same results and even generate exactly the same query execution plan.